# How to achieve many to many releationship between mongoose models

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

2 models City and Category, I have to map many categories to many cities

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: created an array of category in City model, Is there any other way to do?

Comment: Array of Category in City model, would solve that. Any reason for looking for another way?

Comment: I want to find all cities belongs to a category, What approach we can use to get it?